# Best practice to eliminate magic numbers within a member function

Tags: ruby

I have a method that uses a magic number repeatedly, but only in one method.

```
class Foo
  def Bar(str)
     year = str[0..1].to_i + 2000
     month = str[2].ord - 48
     day = str[3].ord - 48
     hour = str[4].ord - 48
     min = str[5].ord - 48
     sec = str[6].ord - 48

     # ...
  end
end
```

[If you wonder about the need to use `ord` here rather than `to_i`, you might like to see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21784998/241536) for more context.]

I'd like to eliminate the `48` magic number here. The only place where this magic number will be used is this specific method. I can't declare it as a constant within the method:

```
class Foo
  def Bar
    ADJ = 48
    month = str[2].ord - ADJ
    day = str[3].ord - ADJ
    hour = str[4].ord - ADJ
    min = str[5].ord - ADJ
    sec = str[6].ord - ADJ
    # ...
  end
end
```

because that results in a `dynamic constant assignment (SyntaxError)` error.  Since `ADJ` here applies only to this method, it doesn't make a lot of sense to me to make it a class variable.

This function will be called frequently; I'd like the solution to at least not be slow.

In C++, I might make it a `static const unsigned` within the method, or move it to an unnamed `namespace`.

What's the Rubyist way to eliminate this magic number?

Comment: The Rubyist way is to not use `ord` but use `to_i`, and to not use methods starting with a capital.

Comment: @sawa:  Because I need the ASCII code of that character.  For example, if `str[2]` contains the letter `=`, I need to get `61`.  Calling `to_i` would return `0`.  Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You may be able to do it that way, but if you care about doing it the Ruby way, using `ord` is definitely not the way to go in the first place. Your code is encoding-dependent. That is a very bad practice.

Comment: @sawa:  hmm, I feel another question coming on...

Comment: In short, your question is contradictory. You are asking for a Ruby way to use `ord`, where using it is against the Ruby way.

Comment: @sawa:  I'll take your assertion to be true, but 1) I don't understand why, 2) This question isn't really about `ord` directly.  It;s about eliminating a magic number that is needed only in one method.  If this method did something else entirely and didn't use `ord` but still needed a magic number, the question still persists.

Comment: The point is that the idea of using a magic number is against Ruby way. Among the various usages of magic numbers, if you can replace them with symbols, then that is Ruby way. Having symbols or other constants used repeatedly is not against Ruby as long as they are not magic numbers.

Comment: @sawa:  That's why I'm trying to eliminate it.  I'll ask a different question.  Hold on...

Comment: @sawa:  Here's my follow-up question about using `ord` and how to do what I need to do.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784998/rubyist-way-to-decode-this-encoded-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to just use a variable.

```
adj = 48
```

You don't get the protection a constant would give you against the value being changed, but the variable is only scoped to a single method. It should not be difficult to ensure through looking at the code and unit testing that the method behaves as expected.

Comment: Would this variable be instantiated every time the method is called?  Would that that be contradictory to this solution "not being slow"?

Comment: @JohnDibling: possibly, but I think that performance concern falls into the "micro-optimization" category.  For this (or any application) there are probably bigger performance concerns than creating a variable.

Comment: Fortunately, `48` is an immutable object, so it is not instantiated every time. The variable pointing to it will be recreated every time, but that is comparable to incrementing an index `i` within a loop.

Comment: Well I thought about it and decided you're probably right.  I'm not writing a feed handler in C++ here -- I'm just writing a utility tool to decode captured network data in to a human-readable format.  Worrying about repeated small allocations here is a micro-optimization, whereas in writing the feed handler it would get you shot in a code review.  It all comes down to context.

Comment: @JohnDibling If you are concerned about performance in any context, I would strongly advise benchmarking the code involved. It may well be that my answer performs worse than other answers.

Answer (score 2):

You should move this constant to the class/module definition.

It's better to move your method to a module and add constant there:

```
module Foo
    XYZ = ...

    def bar
         ...
    end
end
```

Comment: Even though it doesn't apply to the whole class?  That seems like poor design to me, but I might be stuck in a C++ mindset.

Comment: Usually, if your method doesn't fit into class, you should move it to the module and move constant to the module definition.

Comment: But it seems to me that the *method* **does** fit within the class.

Comment: Modules are highly used in ruby to combine multiple methods under single file/namespace.