# Rubyist way to decode this encoded string assuming invariant ASCII encoding

Tags: ruby

My program is a decoder for a binary protocol.  One of the fields in that binary protocol is  an encoded `String`.  Each character in the `String` is printable, and represents an integral value.  According to the spec of the protocol I'm decoding, the integral value it represents is taken from the following table, where all possible characters are listed:

```
Character   Value
=========   =====
0           0
1           1
2           2
3           3
     [...]
:           10
;           11
<           12
=           13
     [...]
B           18
```

So for example, the character `=` represents an integral `13`.

My code was originally using `ord` to get the ASCII code for the character, and then subtracting `48` from that, like this:

```
def Decode(val)
  val[0].ord - 48
end
```

...which works perfectly, assuming that `val` consists only of characters listed in that table (this is verified elsewhere).

However, in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784206/best-practice-to-eliminate-magic-numbers-within-a-member-function#21784206), I was told that:

> You are asking for a Ruby way to use ord, where using it is against
>   the Ruby way.

It seems to me that `ord` is exactly what I need here, so I don't understand why using `ord` here is not a Rubyist way to do what I'm trying to do.

So my questions are:

First and foremost, what is the Rubyist way to write my function above?
Secondary, *why* is using `ord` here a non-Rubyist practice?

A note on encoding:  This protocol which I'm decoding specifies precisely that these strings are ASCII encoded.  No other encoding is possible here.  Protocols like this are extremely common in my industry (stock & commodity markets).

Comment: I see. Code dealing with low level logic may need to use `ord`, but it cannot be a Rubyistic part of the code. It should be an ugly part of the code that should be hidden in a directory as a wrapper/adaptor to be called from the main logic on a separate file. By the way, integral? You probably mean integer.

Comment: If specification guarantees that strings will always be ASCII, then you can use `ord`, no problem. Why it is "non-ruby way" - I cannot tell. :)

Comment: The purpose of the whole code was not clear from the information given in the question at the time I commented. It looked like the OP was just trying to extract numbers out of a string using `ord` instead of `to_i`.

Comment: @sawa:  Re: "it cannot be a Rubyistic part of the code."  This statement seems odd to me.  It seems to imply that a Rubyist methodology cannot be employed to accomplish arbitrary tasks.  Rather, only Rubyist tasks can be accomplished using Rubyist methodologies.

Comment: Ruby can do a wide variety of things, but not all of them are Rubyist. There are Rubyist things that Ruby can do, and non-Rubyist things that Ruby can do. If anything that can be done using Ruby is Rubyist, then the word "Rubyist" would be a trivial, useless word.

Comment: @sawa:  Well, you confused me again, but that's OK.  Confusion is the genesis of wisdom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the Rubyistic way, and faster, to decode the string into an array of integers is the `unpack` method:

```
"=01:".unpack("C*").map {|v| v - 48}
>> [13, 0, 1, 10]
```

The [`unpack`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String%3aunpack) method, with `"C*"` param, converts each character to an 8-bit unsigned integer.

Comment: +1: I am using `unpack` *extensively* throught my code, but I didn't realize it could do this directly.  Actually I hadn't thought of re-processing the output of `unpack` with `map`.

Comment: However it surprises me that you assert that this would be faster.

Comment: I guess it is faster because the `unpack` method it is fully implemented in C code.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `ord` is entirely safe and appropriate in your case, as the source data should always be encoded the same way. Especially if when reading the data you set the encoding to `'US-ASCII'` (although the format used looks safe for 'ASCII-8BIT', 'UTF-8' and 'ISO-8859', which may be the point of it - it seems resilient to many conversions, and does not use all possible byte values). However, `ord` is *intended* to be used with character semantics, and technically you want byte semantics. With basic ASCII and variants there is no practical difference, all byte values below 128 are the same character code.

I would suggest using `String#unpack` as a general method for converting binary input to Ruby data types, but there is not an `unpack` code for "use this byte with an offset", so that becomes a two-part process.